# Cannot invoke contract function from console using truffle

Tags: contract-invocation

I am working my through the book Ethereum for Dummies, and have created a contract HelloWorld, deployed to the blockchain and all is good until I try to invoke the function of the contract.

My contract code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-License
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract HelloWorld { 
string private helloMessage = "Hello World";

function getHelloMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
    return helloMessage;
    }
}
```

compiling, deployment and all requisite steps went fine, albeit with some corrections to the code as it appears all of packages have been updated a lot since the Dummies books was released.

Using the truffle console, entering the command

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance });
```

I get the desired output, which according to the book should allow me to invoke the function on the contract with the following command:

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.getHelloWorld() });
```

The response is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: instance.getHelloWorld is not a function
```

Given the book is somewhat out of date, I searched online, including similar articles in this forum but I cannot seem to find anything that matches the syntax above. As I am new to all of this I imagine my lack of familiarity with truffle is probably why I am missing how to fix this... I would be most appreciative for anyone who can point me in the right direction.

My development setup is as follows:
Truffle v5.5.25 (core: 5.5.25)
Ganache v7.4.0
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v18.7.0
Web3.js v1.7.4

Comment: In the contract the function is called `getHelloMessage`, but you are calling `getHelloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

In the contract the function is called `getHelloMessage`, but you are calling `getHelloWorld`.

You should type in the console

```
HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(instance) {return instance.getHelloMessage() })
```